# RxJava 2 - How to compare first and second result of a concat

Tags: android, rx-java2, concatenation

I'm trying to use the concat() operator in order to get the result of the database and network, doing a set of operations with each result object.

However, I have some operations which should only be done once, i.e. once I have the first successful result, they should be skipped if other result is different than the first one, or if the first result is not successful it should be done with the second result.

I do not want to block any of the operators that depends on any of the Database or Network result, they should be done right away whenever each  result is available.

For now I created a sample project and I have something like this:

```
  val flowable1 = Flowable.just(1)
  val flowable2 = Flowable.just(2).delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

  Flowable.concat(flowable1, flowable2)
                .map {
                    //operation that should be done every time
                    Log.d("TAG", "Printing result=$it")
                    return@map it
                }
                .map {
                    //it should also be different than previous result (it)
                    //this operation should only be done when there is a 
                    //valid result but only once                    
                    if(it != 0) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Printing only once=$it")
                    }
                    return@map it
                }
                .subscribe {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Printing the results=$it")
                }
```

For now the result of the code above will be:

```
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing result=1
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing only once=1
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing the results=1
2019-01-23 10:31:31.233 15747-16271/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing result=2
2019-01-23 10:31:31.233 15747-16271/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing only once=2
2019-01-23 10:31:31.233 15747-16271/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing the results=2
```

What I want for the code above:

```
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing result=1
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing only once=1
2019-01-23 10:31:29.231 15747-15747/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing the results=1
2019-01-23 10:31:31.233 15747-16271/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing result=2
2019-01-23 10:31:31.233 15747-16271/com.te.example D/TAG: Printing the results=2
```

Any one knows how can I do the map operator in order to print once the second map operator, comparing the first Int result is not equal to the latest result?

Comment: have a look at `distinct` and `distinctUntil` or `takeIf` or `filter` and see what works for you

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns, according to the documentation, I think `distinctUntilChanged()` might be useful, I will try with it to see if it works, thank you

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns, `distinctUntilChanged()` kinda works, however, from that point on I no longer have access to previous emitted objects in order to only block some operators, not all of them

Comment: @iGoDa What do you mean with `to only block some operators`? `distinctUntilChanged()` blocks every duplicit item from being emitted. If you want to process both items from DB and API use `doOnNext()` operator before distinct.

Comment: Hi @skywall, you are right `distinctUntilChanged()` blocks every item emitted, which is not what I wanted. 
With `doOnNext` I cannot use rxjava operators, since I may want to do a request or not according to the comparison of the previous and current value.
However reading the list of available operators I saw `scan()`, this operator allows me to check the previous value if has any and the current value, with this I  think I can make conditions to execute operators or not.